# How the below React js code formatCount function works?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, ternary-operator

I'm learning React.js and facing the below confusing code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Counter extends Component {
    state = { 
        counts:1
     };
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
                <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button>Increment</button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
    formatCount(){
        const {counts} = this.state;
        return counts === 0 ? 'Zero' : counts
    }
}
export default Counter;
```

A few things confuse me:

1.`state` is an object rather than a number, but in this line `const {counts} = this.state;` why assigning an object to a number?

2.Why using `{}` on counts, but the next line, no `{}` around counts, `return counts === 0 ? 'Zero' : counts`?

Comment: `const {counts} = this.state;` is called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). `counts === 0 ? 'Zero' : counts` is a use of the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: But I never declare variable counts inside formatCount(), so where is it from?

Comment: `counts` is "destructured" out from the `this.state` object. It is essentially a shortcut for writing `const counts = this.state.counts;`

Comment: Deconstructing `counts` from `this.state` is not necessary but it makes the statements that follow potentially easier to read. You could also just write `formatCount() { return this.state.counts === 0 ? 'Zero' : this.state.counts; }`

Comment: @Tholle Can I shortcut counts, then assign to a different variable, for example, counting, in one step?

Comment: You can rename the variable with `const { counts: newCountsName } = this.state`, or you can use previously destructured values as default for new ones, e.g. `const { counts, countsPlusOne = counts + 1 } = this.state`. You should in my opinion not go overboard with it though, since it will get harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const {counts} = this.state;` is called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and is essentially a shorter way of writing this:

```
const counts = this.state.counts;
```

`return counts === 0 ? 'Zero' : counts` is a use of the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and can e.g. be used instead of if/else statements like this one:

```
if (counts === 0) {
  return 'Zero';
} else {
  return counts;
}
```